# Как удалить обертку (тег) pre?

Tags: php

У меня со стороны клиента иногда (т.е. не всегда) приходят данные в обертке (тэге) `pre`, возможно ли как-то удалить этот тег (на стороне сервера!), но контент оставить как есть?

Comment: Можно ещё 

    $nopre = str_replace(array("<pre>","</pre>"),array("",""),$pre);

Но тогда можно прибить другие пре как данные....


Вообще это явное извращение, надо искать другое архитектурное решение для связи клиента-сервера

Comment: кстати уж не знаю почему: `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function length()`

Comment: надо strlen

Comment: Вообще почитайте доки по php?

Comment: ну уж извращение или нет, но иногда пользователь может и от руки вбить в редактор данные и скопи-пастить, вот и получается при копи-пасте появляется еще один ненужный тег pre, а потом выводится <pre><pre>данные</pre></pre> (не оч круто).

Comment: да, дей-но, тогда на стороне клиента можно сделать такую фичу, типо если стоит два подряд pre, то один удаляй нафик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типа так:

```
  $pre = $_REQUEST["CLIENT_DATA"];
  $nopre = substr($pre,strlen("<pre>"));
  $nopre = substr($nopre,0, strlen($nopre)-strlen("</pre>"));
```

:-)

Comment: а это будет работать если допустим там pre не оказалось, т.е. все равно контент нужно получить этот же? Ключевое слово **иногда**

Comment: Ну тогда добавить `if(substr($pre,0, strlen("<pre>"))=="<pre>")`

Answer (score 1):

Ну если в `<pre>` приходит не `html\xml`, то есть замечательная функция [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<pre>'); // удалить только <pre>
```

Comment: увы, приходит именно html\xml. Я вижу выход только в правке на клиенте, но как определить что два pre подряд стоят вот это уже загадка.

Comment: $($("user data input").val()).children("pre").size()>0 ?

Comment: Ответ ошибочен. Ваш пример удалит все теги **КРОМЕ** тега `<pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_replace('/^(<pre[^>]+>)+/', '', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/(<\/pre>)+$/', '', $content);
```

Если клиент копипастит совсем-совсем криво.

Answer (score 0):

Если используете jQuery, то я бы [предложил такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/4vWAX/2/) - замена тега **pre** (методы [.replaceWith()  .replaceAll()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)), на какой-то более подходящий вам.